# promlexport: command not found

Tags: terminal, rbenv

Tried to install something via terminal and got sucked into a rabbit hole and accidentally deleted some shit (incl. Ruby & rbenv). Now whenever I open terminal it automatically feeds me this:

```
-bash: promlexport: command not found
-bash: rbenv: command not found
-bash: rbenv: command not found
-bash: rbenv: command not found
-bash: rbenv: command not found
```

I get that rbenv isn't working right now, but wtf is promlexport? I've googled it and literally 0 relevant searches come up… I'm working on a mac using the beta OS X Yosemite.

This is my .bash_profile (if that means anything to you — sure doesn't to me):

```
function proml {
  case $TERM in 
   xterm*)
   TITLEBAR='\[\0033]0;\u!\h:\w\007\]'
   ;;
   *)
   TITLEBAR=""
   ;;
 esac
PS1="\u: \p\e[32m\1\W\[\e[0m\]l\n\[\e[0.31m\]❤️ \[\e[0m\]"
}
promlexport PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

PS – Might this be fixed when I update to the public OS X Yosemite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the following from my .bash_profile:

```
promlexport PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Of course, it fixed everything. Instead of trying to reinstall rbenv, I successfully installed rvn. Definitely a "duh" moment, but more importantly, a learning one.